# Nav Loading Delay

Tags: html, css, nav

I've noticed an odd loading issue on a site that I built. When the navigation links load at the top of the page, they are displayed in the left hand corner of the browser in their un-stylized form, with bullets, underlines, etc. before loading. **Is there a way that I can code this differently so that it hides the loading process?**

Here's a couple of images showing the problem during the page load:

**Nav Loading:** 
[image: Nav Loading]

**Nav Loaded:**
[image: Nav Loaded]

**Here's a copy of the CSS:**

```
/*Header Link Wrap & Align*/

#nav-wrap { 
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 52px;
    background-image: url(/images/hlink-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

}


#nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}

#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#nav a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 18px 9px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ffa500;
    color: #fff9;
}




.head-divider {
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0;
    width:2px;
    height:52px;
    background-image:url(/images/h-divider.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="nav-wrap">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="homes.php">Custom Homes</a></li>
    <li class="head-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="inspections.php">Inspection Services</a></li>
    <li class="head-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="energy.php">Energy Audits</a></li>
    <li class="head-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="complete-services.php">Complete Services</a></li>
    <li class="head-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="head-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.newdayhomes.us/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>  
</div>
```

***Your help is greatly appreciated!***

Comment: Can you post a link to your page?

Comment: Move your scripts to the bottom of your file. So that they load last. This will speed up your page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your script calls so that they come after your CSS calls. What's happening is that when the page is being loaded, the browser is waiting for the scripts to be loaded before it moves on to reading your stylesheets, causing a flash of unstyled content.

Comment: Hi Zak, thank you for the info - could we go to chat? I'm not sure how to setup a chat.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your server is slow. Is your stylesheet for the #nav is in a different host or something?

Try adding those styles to your `<head>` section and see. If you have images, but still basic HTML, CSS must load fast.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, I realized that my Header PHP inclusion was loading after the Scripts & CSS,

So I placed it at the very top of the page, it's loading much faster now. Thank you for your help!